Combining SQL and Regex together?
I have a table pizza_orders with a column ingredients that looks like this:



order_no
ingredients




1
cheese-olives-peppers-olives


2
cheese-olives


3
cheese-tomatoes-olives


4
cheese



I want to make 3 new variables:

x1: everything from the start position to the first - (e.g. cheese, cheese, cheese, cheese_
x2: everything after the first - to the second - (e.g. olives, olives, tomatoes, NULL)
x3: everything from the second - to the end position (e.g. peppers, NULL, olives, NULL)

I tried to use this link here to learn how to do it: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netezza?topic=ref-regexp-extract-2
SELECT 
    order_no,
    ingredients,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(ingredients, '([^\\-]*)', 1) AS x1,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(ingredients, '\\-([^\\-]*)', 1) AS x2,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(ingredients, '\\-[^\\-]*\\-(.*)', 1) AS x3
FROM 
    pizza_orders;

x1 is coming out correctly, but x2 and x3 are not. Can someone help me correct the regex?

This is what we call a broken schema design. It's pretty much never a good idea to put delimited data in a single column. This design cries out for an additional table, or if there will never be more than four toppings then each topping should get its own column. Fix the schema (because it really is broken), and suddenly this problem is trivial.

select ingredients,

translate(regexp_extract(ingredients||'-','[a-zA-Z]*-',1,1),'-',''),
translate(regexp_extract(ingredients||'-','[a-zA-Z]*-',1,2),'-',''),
translate(regexp_extract(ingredients||'-','[a-zA-Z]*-',1,3),'-',''),
translate(regexp_extract(ingredients||'-','[a-zA-Z]*-',1,4),'-','')

from pizza_orders;

